# Making an html table using data from text file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an HTML table to sell materials for a shop. The data for each material is stored into a text file. I am trying to convert my text file to a hash table so i can call each part of data for a specific material to make a table in HTML. I can't seam to find a good way to do this with only javascript and html.

I have already tried using the p5js library to bring in my text but then I don't know how to split it and call the index for each material.

Here is what one line of the text file looks like: 
  21;rondelles de 3/4"";6.95;3.48;C7;8;mc

Comment: Do you have to use your own format for the text file, or can you use any format?

Comment: please show what you tried already, then we can help you fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Well, i think that i will use a json file instead. My problem now is that i can't load my local file as a variable. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirements allow it, use [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp).

Your stored data would the look something like this:

```
{
  "21": [
    "rondelles de 3/4\"\"",
    "6.95",
    "3.48",
    "C7",
    "8",
    "mc"
  ],
  "12": [
    "rondelles de 3/4\"\"",
    "4.95",
    "1.48",
    "A7",
    "4",
    "mc"
  ]
}
```

With the assumptions that `21` and `12` are your material ids.

With JSON you can also easily use keys instead of array indices for your data

```
{
  "21": [
    "description": "rondelles de 3/4\"\"",
    "outerDiameter": "6.95",
    "innerDiameter": "3.48",
    "type": "C7",
    "size": "8",
    "standard": "mc"
  ],
  "12": [
    "description": "rondelles de 3/4\"\"",
    "outerDiameter": "4.95",
    "innerDiameter": "1.48",
    "type": "A7",
    "size": "4",
    "standard": "mc"
  ]
}
```

(I have assumed some property keys but you can use any that you like)

To parse the code you can the simply use

`var materials = JSON.parse(data)`

and access materials by their id like this:

`var mat12 = materials[12]`

Converting a map to text is as easy as this:

`JSON.stringify([...map])`

Or if you just use regular JS objects and not Maps then it becomes even easier:

`JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: That JSON file looks really promessing! Is there anyway that i can load my txt.json directly into my js file?

Comment: Yes, of course! Do you want to load the file from a server or from your local machine?

Comment: from the same folder as my javascript file

Comment: You can find two solutions [here](http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/open-a-local-file-with-javascript.html). For loading files from a server you should use the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to parse your text file correctly you must obey some rules.

- the "" quotes need to be escaped like \"\"
- instead of putting each dataset on a new line I'd recommend adding a \n at the end of a line. This way you can split the dataset into a javascript array quite easily.
- semicolons between values is great

Say you have a textfile like this:

> 21;rondelles de 3/4\"\";6.95;3.48;C7;8;mc\n
>
> 12;rondelles de 3/4\"\";4.95;1.48;A7;4;mc

(which you've successfully loaded and assigned to a string)

then you can do something like this:

```js
var textFile = "21;rondelles de 3/4\"\";6.95;3.48;C7;8;mc\n12;rondelles de 3/4\"\";4.95;1.48;A7;4;mc";
var temp = textFile.split("\n");
var data = new Array();
for (var a = 0; a < temp.length; a++) {
  data[a] = new Array();
  data[a] = temp[a].split(";");
}
console.log(data);
```